# React closing a dropdown when click outside

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Building a custom dropdown in React and came across a problem when trying to close it when clicking outside.
So i created generic HOC so i can use it for other ocasions as well.

The problem i seem to have is i don't know hwo to pass the `ref` from the hoc to the component.

I've been looking into [forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) and other tones of examples, but i can't figure it out.
Any idea if it's possible and how i could do it?

[Codesandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-withclickoutside-c95gt?file=/src/Home.js)

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export default function withClickOutside(WrappedComponent) {
  const Component = (props) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    const ref = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
      const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
        if (!ref?.current?.contains(event.target)) {
          setOpen(false);
        }
      };
      document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    }, [ref]);

    return <WrappedComponent {...props} open={open} setOpen={setOpen} ref={ref}/>;
  };

  return Component;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to handle the `ref` passed so that it actually attaches to something:

```
const Home = forwardRef(({ open, setOpen }, ref) => {
  console.log(open);

  return (
    <section ref={ref}>
      <h1>Feels good to be home!</h1>

      <button className="secondary" onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
        Dropdown Toggle
      </button>

      {open && (
        <ul>
          <li>One</li>
          <li>Two</li>
        </ul>
      )}
    </section>
  );
});
```

[image: Edit React withClickOutside (forked)]

Answer (score 30):

**Simple follow 5 steps to close menu/ change state of any element when clicked outside of that element using React Hook**

**Step 1 : import useRef and define a variable**

```
import {useRef} from "react"

const catMenu = useRef(null)
```

**Step 2 : use React Hook for state chnage (useState)**

```
  const [openSlide, setopenSlide] = useState("");
```

**Step 3 : Define a javascript function to set state**

```
   const closeOpenMenus = (e)=>{
    if(openSlide && !catMenu.current?.contains(e.target)){
      setopenSlide(false)
    }
}
```

**Step 4 : Add a event listener on when mouse is down anywhere in document**

```
 document.addEventListener('mousedown',closeOpenMenus)
```

**Step 5 : Select target element (ref={variable_name})**

```
<div ref={catMenu}>... </div>
```

Comment: In Step 2, you initialized the 'openSlide' variable to an empty string,
while in Step 3, you are updating it to a boolean with setopenSlide.
Did you intend to initialize it to 'true' in Step 2?

Comment: This works when I try to close the dropdown on outside click. But dropdown stops closing when I click on the button/div which made it open first.

<button className="pricing_btn" onClick={toggleDropdown}>
     <span className="arrow-down"</span>
 </button>

Answer (score 14):

It is a little diff. from your approach, but this hook can used to wrap your button and menu.

```js
/**
 * This Hook can be used for detecting clicks outside the Opened Menu
 */
function useClickOutside(ref, onClickOutside) {
  useEffect(() => {
    /**
     * Invoke Function onClick outside of element
     */
    function handleClickOutside(event) {
      if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
        onClickOutside();
      }
    }
    // Bind
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    return () => {
      // dispose
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, [ref, onClickOutside]);
}
```

Implemented with your code:

```js
const Home = () => {
  let [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const wrapperRef = useRef("menu");
  useClickOutside(wrapperRef, () => {
    setOpen(false);
  });

  return (
    <section>
      <h1>Feels good to be home!</h1>
      <div ref={wrapperRef}>
        <button className="secondary" onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
          Dropdown Toggle
        </button>

        {open && (
          <ul>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go about it in React is using a Callback and useEffect hooks:
This example is for a mobile menu close on outside and it works the same with whichever element you want to close, simply add the ref={element} in order to trigger the close.

```
  const [toggleNav, setToggleNav] = useState(false);
  const mobileMenuRef = useRef();

  const closeOpenMenus = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      if (
        mobileMenuRef.current &&
        toggleNav &&
        !mobileMenuRef.current.contains(e.target)
      ) {
        setToggleNav(false);
      }
    },
    [toggleNav]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", closeOpenMenus);
  }, [closeOpenMenus]);
```

Comment: Thank you. This actually worked for me. I was also using a global context with a useState boolean hook to manage the menu's state.

This solution worked for my case

Answer (score 1):

```
import {useEffect, useRef, useState} from "react";

export default function Page(){
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)
  
  const btnRef = useRef()
  
  useEffect(() => {
        const closeDropdown = e => {
            if (!btnRef.current.contains(e.target)) {
                setIsOpen(false);
            }
        }
        document.body.addEventListener('click', closeDropdown)
        return () => document.body.removeEventListener('click', closeDropdown)
    }, [])
  
  return (
    <>
      <div ref={btnRef}>Open</div>
      { isOpen && (
        <div>
          Some block
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addtion to `@Mriganka Ghosh`'s answer, there will be some cases when we want to add 'exceptions' to the outside boundary.

We can do something like this:

```
function useOutsideAlerter(
    ref: any,
    handleClick: () => void,
    exceptionElementsRef: React.MutableRefObject<any>[]
) {
   useEffect(() => {
      function handleClickOutside(event: any) {
           if (exceptionElementsRef.some((exceptionElement) => 
               exceptionElement.current.contains(event.target))
              ) return;

      if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
           handleClick();
      }
      }

      document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
      return () => {
           document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
      };
    }, [ref]);
}
```

And:

```
function OutsideClickHandler({ children, handleClick, exceptionElementsRef }: any) {
    const wrapperRef = useRef(null);
    useOutsideAlerter(wrapperRef, handleClick, exceptionElementsRef);

    return <div ref={wrapperRef}>{children}</div>;
}
```

P.S: Sorry for my bad Typescript types.