# React vs JS event handlers for clicking outside the component, which one is best practice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, javascript-events

I am creating a menu component in React where when the menu opens, and user clicks anywhere outside the menu it'll close the menu component. There are two approaches I saw, one is to use JS event listener like this

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Dropdown = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  
  const toggleDropdown = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
      if (isOpen && !event.target.closest('.dropdown')) {
        setIsOpen(false);
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, [isOpen]);

  return (
    <div className="dropdown" onClick={toggleDropdown}>
      {isOpen ? (
        <div className="dropdown-menu">
          {/* Dropdown Content */}
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Another approach would be in with React event handler like this:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Dropdown = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  // Toggle Dropdown open/close
  const toggleDropdown = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

  // Close Dropdown if open, when clicking outside
  const handleClickOutside = (e) => {
    if (isOpen && !e.currentTarget.contains(e.target)) {
      setIsOpen(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div onClick={handleClickOutside}>
      <button onClick={(e) => {
        e.stopPropagation(); // Prevents click from "bubbling" up to the div
        toggleDropdown();
      }}>
        Toggle Dropdown
      </button>
      {isOpen && (
        <div className="dropdown-menu">
          {/* Dropdown content */}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

so which one is more of a best practice ? on one hand you have to assign global event listeners, on one hand you are dealing with event bubbling in react.

Comment: Where's the `<button>` in the first solution?

Comment: The second one attaches `handleClickOutside` only to a tiny div, not to the whole document. That's probably not the behaviour you want?

Comment: @Bergi yea you are correct, the tiny div was just a reference for the whole document, which didn't reflect it clearly, thats where i am kind of confused, i see bunch of solutions on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63359138/react-closing-a-dropdown-when-click-outside) that suggests     document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
but that is breaking the react pattern and best practices right, so im wondering if it's the best way.

Comment: "*that is breaking the react pattern and best practices*" - I wouldn't say that. You *want* global state (the whole document) to be affected when the dropdown opens, right? Then `useEffect` is the proper way to do that from any component mounted anywhere.

Comment: If you were to model the whole document as a react application, you could potentially have some global state or shared store to keep track of the currently active dropdown, pass that (or at least a way to register an open dropdown's close handler) down to the component using the context api, and have the click handler attached to the root node of your application. But typical react applications don't control the entire document, they are mounted at some part of the page, and still have to use dom apis for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the idiomatic way is for anything within React to be React. So yea, stick to synthetic events. Bear in mind that this is only applicable in "reactive" behavior.

Set that aside for a moment, and instead focus on Event API. So, once you click a button, that button gains focus. Once you click something else, said button loses focus and fires the blur event. Now, instead of listening to a generic click event we can ulitlize this, and thus:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export function Foo(props) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)

  const handleBlur = (e) => {
    setIsOpen(false)
  }

  const handlePointer = (e) => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onPointerDown={handlePointer} onBlur={handleBlur}>Click me</button>
      {isOpen ? <div>I'm showing!</div> : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Don't mind me registering onPointerDown instead of onClick. It's a force of habit.
Here's the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event)